# How to resize an image smoothly (with resampling) using Windows API calls?

Tags: windows, vb6, gdi+

I need to resize images and resample them so they don't end up all jagged (I think that's called aliasing).

I found some code (sorry, lost the link) that does this in pure VB6 code but it's a bit slow (2-5 seconds) and I'm displaying pictures in real time so I need something faster.

I seem to recall seeing some examples of doing this with the GDI+ library. An example in VB6 would be ideal, but I can probably work with a simple example with Windows API calls in another language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WIA 2.0's Scale filter seems to do a decent job.  [Windows® Image Acquisition Automation Library v2.0 Tool: Image acquisition and manipulation component for VB and scripting](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en)

No need for any funky .Net interop.

Comment: dead link. couldn't find the new, can you?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18287&mnui=0 is dead too, just like http://download.microsoft.com/download/WinXPHome/Utility/2.0/WXP/EN-US/WIAAutSDK.zip cannot find `WIAAutSDK.zip`. in case you still have that file from authentic sources, could you provide a hash or fingerprint of it?

Comment: Good news: all supported versions of Windows include WIA 2.0.  Microsoft has pulled most of the support downloads for Windows XP and older because nobody is supposed to be using XP anymore.  This link might get you to it but beware: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/cant-download-wia-automation-from-microsoft/e5e2fd23-63e2-4481-837c-6058995103f1

Comment: MD5 of the file I have: 8CB74B82DD53BD48EB1F1F33A59D08E0

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. Create a [VB.net library that can return pictures](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_move_picture_vbnet_to_vb6.html) to a VB6 program.
2. Write some VB.Net to [resize pictures without anti-aliasing](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_antialias_images.html).

Alternatively Rod Stephen's book [Visual Basic Graphics Programming](http://www.vb-helper.com/vbgp.htm) apparently explains how to do it all in VB6.

Or try to call GDI+ from VB6. Here's a [wrapper and type library](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/vbmedia/using_gdi_plus/GDIPlus_Helper/article.asp), good luck! ("[Bring your hatchet](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/bringyourhatchet.htm)!")